# External js file not getting load in Truffle test

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-test, unittesting

I'm writing up test cases for my smart contract. Here is the folder structure:

```
- bin
- build
- contracts
    - mytestfile.sol
- modules
    - mymodule.js
- test
    - mytestfile.js
truffle.js
```

I want to use one of the function from module file, hence I'm trying to load `mymodule.js` file into `mytestfile.js` in a following way.

```
var module = require('../modules/mymodule');
```

However, when I add upper line, truffle test stop working and displaying following output:

[image]

If I comment it out, it starts executing other test cases. I have also tried by adding `.js` extension.

Am I missing anything here?

**Edit:**
Here is a sample of the module file:

```
module.exports = {
verify : function(){

    }
}
```

Comment: I've something similar with my tests and it is working correctly. Perhaps your module is importing something that conflicts with Truffle tests.

Comment: @Ismael: not sure what is the issue, but when I add that line in my test case it's working fine! global declaration has some issue..